# Three reasons why $\mathbb{N}$ the set of all natural numbers is not a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I understand the absence of identity and additive inverse what is the third reason?

Comment: No multiplicative inverse?

Comment: Vector space over what?  $\mathbb R$?  $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: No field of scalars under which it's closed by scalar multiplication.

Comment: "Absence of identity": what? $\Bbb N$ has an *additive* identity ($=0$). Vector spaces do not have multiplicative identity.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli $0$ is not in the natural numbers for many definitions of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, $\Bbb{N}$ is not universally defined  to include 0.  Some people/instructors/authors do and some don't.  In this case it seems that OP is one of the latter.

Comment: why it cannot ... ask better how to chose the operations to build a vector space only with the elements of $N$. It's not lost in advance since the question is **with** $N$ ...

Answer (score 4):

It fails to have scalar multiplication over a field like $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.

(And $\Bbb N$ can't be a vector space over $\Bbb N$ since the natural numbers are not a field to begin with since they lack multiplicative inverses.)

Comment: What's the relevance of the natural numbers not being a field?  $\Bbb{R}[x]$ is also not a field for the same reason, but it is a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: I wasn't sure the best way to phrase it, but the point I was intending is that you can't have $\Bbb N$ as a vector space over $\Bbb N$ since it isn't a field.

Answer (score 1):

Scalar multiplication.

A vector space is closed under scalar multiplication.

The scalar isn't in the vector space, and can be in a real number.

$cn$  is not necessarily in $\mathbb N$